# Discord Py on_message bot=False blocked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to test why on_message() with bot=False isn't picking up other messages in my testing server. This works with a bot but not with self.

```py
@discord.events
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "whisk":
        print(f"{message.author}: Hello")

    await Discord.process_commands(message)
```

This should print whisk in console which it does on the bot and self but when its ran on self and another user says "whisk" it doesn't print anything. On the bot it does print.

Comment: You shouldn't be making a self bot, it's [against Discord's TOS](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-) and can result in getting all your accounts banned

Comment: I know... this is for testing purposes.... thats why I am asking whys it blocked you dont have to tell me that is against TOS....

Comment: Why are you even testing it if you know that self bots are against the rules?

Comment: sound very fishy to me, bots tend to have admin permissions, using a self bot to bypass restrictions and use discord with bot permissions is strictly against the TOS.

Comment: "use discord with bot permissions" do you mean Oauth?

Comment: Why would anyone try help you or answer your question, if your intention is either to bypass restrictions or cause harm to someone's server, by using the bots permissions to preform actions. Hence the 2 down votes.

Comment: If I was get to admin for every server?? by you saying bypassing restrictions wouldn't there be a lot of discord attacks?!

Comment: You can easily test "how a bot and a client work" simply by using a normal bot rather than a self-bot. It's an immensely reduced risk from something that will most likely get your account terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most probably because of versions 1.7 have been stripped of all self bot methods.

If you want to Selfbot you either go with an outdated, unsupported and unmaintained library or interact directly with the API. In any case you're breaking ToS and you won't receive any support on any official channel.

There is no allowed use for selfbots at all. Even just connecting to the API without even receiving or sending a single message breaks the ToS.

You can only use OAuth2 protocol to make requests on behalf of a user account.

Comment: I tried both versions 1.5 and 1.7 still the same results.
Working before at the start of May.

Comment: Ohh yeah discord also changed the API and selfbots only see their own messages. https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/6839

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
import discord
import os
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('whisk'):
        await message.channel.send('hello')
```

see if that works

Comment: using `message.content.startswith` instead of `message.content ==` doesn't answer the question.